# GCC Compiled program not running in a new Window

Tags: compiling, scripts, gcc, c, executable

**What i am Doing?**

I have created a simple c Program that runs and executes a system Command the code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH_OF_THE_STRING 200
//int main()
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmd[LENGTH_OF_THE_STRING]= "";
    char **p;

    fgets (cmd, LENGTH_OF_THE_STRING, stdin);

    system(cmd);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**How i am doing it?**

I am compiling and generating the outpul using gcc like this

```
gcc -o MyProgram FileName.c
```

**What i am facing?**

After the successful generation of the output file when i try to run it on double click it does not execute. While it does execute from terminal like this `./MyProgram`

**What should i do?**

.

**Note:**

> I have already added permissions for the execution of the file and
>   also changed Read Only to even Read and Write

Answer (score 1):

right-click on output file and under permissions tab check "Allow executing file as program" to make it as executable program.

in terminal use:

```
 $ chmod +x myoutput
```

#### What should you do?

You can not run output compiled .c file under Ubuntu in grapgical window. you need to install [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).It's a full-fledged IDE with a visual form designer, code-editor, and debugger.

You won't need to use the console to compile or run your applications and the Qt framework is easy to learn and use.

There's a great tutorial for [getting started with Qt](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/)

[How to install](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Installing_QT_Creator)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that.. I have already done that

Comment: @NSQuamber.java You can not run output compiled .c file under Ubuntu in grapgical window. you need to install Qt Creator. I have updated answer.

Comment: I recently  downloaded eclipse and its binary is executing directly

Comment: @NSQuamber.java As I told you, you can not run executable .c file in GUI window. you need a graphical application.